# Connect from aws ec2 to remote network

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, vpn

I use Ubuntu and to connect to a remote network I use a default vpn connection. There are settings: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMkBf.png)

- gateway
- user name
- user password
- group name
- group password

One of my docker containers depends on connection with this network. Now I move on docker files to the aws EC2 instance. How can I define the connection on the aws ec2 instance to this network? Or, maybe, can I define this somehow inside a Dockerfile? In the Dockerfile I use the image of Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Supposedly you need the VPN connection to access to AWS environment so if you deploy your app in AWS why would you still need the VPN connection?

Comment: @masseyb no the problem is that some services work on the remote server which is not on the aws it is on a local network, but others are on the aws

Comment: Is setting up a [site-to-site VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) between your local infrastructure and AWS an option? [Does the VPN client you're using support command line runs](https://docstore.mik.ua/univercd/cc/td/doc/product/vpn/client/rel4_0/admin_gd/vcach4.htm#wp1165504)? Can use the client with a config file maybe? e.g. trying to automate the auto-completion of the input in the client GUI would be a pita imho.